# Incrementing one value of a MATLAB array multiple times in one line

Tags: arrays, matlab, increment, vectorization

This is a question about incrementing one value of a MATLAB array multiple times in the same statement, without having to use a for loop.

I set my array as:

```
>> A = [10 20 30];
```

And then run:

```
>> A([1, 1]) = A([1, 1]) + [20 3]

A =

    13    20    30
```

Clearly the 20 is ignored. However, i would like it to be included, so that:

```
>> A = [10 20 30];
>> A([1, 1]) = A([1, 1]) + [20, 3]
```

would give:

```
A =

    33    20    30
```

Is there a function to allow this to be done in a nice, vectorised fashion?

(In reality, the indexing to the array would include multiple indexes, so it could be `[1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 3 3 3]` etc., with an array of numbers to increment by (the `[20, 3]` above) of the same length.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you want to do can be done using the function [ACCUMARRAY](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/accumarray.html), like so:

```
A = [10 20 30];            %# Starting array
index = [1 2 2 1];         %# Indices for increments
increment = [20 10 10 3];  %# Value of increments
A = accumarray([1:numel(A) index].',[A increment]);  %'# Accumulate starting
                                                      %#   values and increments
```

And the output of this example should be:

```
A = [33 40 30];
```

**EDIT:** If `A` is a large array of values, and there are just a few increments to add, the following may be more computationally efficient than the above:

```
B = accumarray(index.',increment);  %'# Accumulate the increments
nzIndex = (B ~= 0);               %# Find the indices of the non-zero increments
A(nzIndex) = A(nzIndex)+B(nzIndex);  %# Add the non-zero increments
```

Comment: Thanks, I've got that first one working a treat. I believe there's a transpose symbol missing on the SUBS though - I could only make `A = accumarray([1:numel(A) index]',[A increment]);` work. I'll do some speed comparisons for the second suggestion once my data's populated.

Comment: @Bill: You're right. I forgot that the first input has to be a column vector in this case. In general, the first input has to be an M-by-N matrix where M is the number of values being accumulated and N is the number of subscripts (1 in this case, but more for multidimensional indexing).

Comment: @Adrien: Don't be surprised. @gnovice is the only user with a golden Matlab badge. That means that he's both fast and right.

Comment: @Jonas: ... or thoroughly addicted to SO. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there's something I don't quite get here, but you're basically trying to add 23 to the first element of A, right? So you can write:

```
A([1, 1]) = A([1, 1]) + sum([20 3])
```

Also, if you have an index array, you can write

```
indexArray = [1 2 2 3 1 1 2 1];
toAdd = [20 3];
A = [10 20 30];

A(indexArray) + sum(toAdd)

ans =
33    43    43    53    33    33    43    33
```

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: Not sure whether it does now, but I've edited the question right while you were writing the comment.

Comment: I think the general case has `toAdd` the same length as `indexArray`.  So if the contents of `indexArray` were unique, you'd just do `A(indexArray) + toAdd`.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: Ah, ok. Yes, that would make sense as well. I'll update my answer with your comment when it becomes clear that this is what the OP wanted, rather than what @gnovice suggests.