# optimising matlab for loop

Tags: matlab

I have this following loop for a code (that computes the histograms). I am writing in Matlab. As I am new to Matlab I don't know of any faster methods to do this. I am currently writing

```
for i=1:size(b)
    a(b(i)) = a(b(i)) + 1;
end
```

Are there any faster methods to do this, preferably those which do not require the for loop?

Comment: general comment: `size` isn't the right function for what you are doing now, rather use [length](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/length.html) or [numel](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/numel.html).

Comment: The idea that for-loops are inefficient/slow and should be replaced if possible is unsubstantiated. Even though you could replace this code with something that is faster, you would probably save only a fraction of a second. This is not the level of code optimization you should be worried about.

Comment: @Kavka Concerning this type of for loop, I would agree. A more complex for loop that manipulates large matrices would be worth vectorizing, right? Matlab was designed to work with Matrices -- all of its matrix operations are supposed to be optimized.

Comment: See also http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/10055

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply vectorize it by `a(b) = a(b) + 1`. Check the following:

```
>> a = [1 2 3 4];
>> b = [2 4]; %# indices to modify. Be sure that they are in bounds.
>> a(b) = a(b) + 1

a =

     1     3     3     5
```

If you use some indices multiple times, then `accumarray` will help as follows:

```
>> a = [1 2 3 4];
>> b = [2 4 2];
>> a = accumarray([1:numel(a) b].',[a ones(size(b))])'

a =

     1     4     3     5
```

Alternatively, you can use:

```
>> a = [1 2 3 4];
>> b = [2 4 2];
>> b = accumarray(b.',ones(size(b)));
>> a(nzIndex) = a(nzIndex) + b(nzIndex)'

a =

     1     4     3     5
```

See [this nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3955156/198428) here for further details.

Comment: In my case b may be [2 4 2], so that I need to increment a(2) twice. This method updates a(2) only once.

Answer (score 1):

If both `a` and `b` are vector, this should work.

```
a = 1:100;
b = 100:-1:1;

a(b) = a(b) + 1;
```